# Difference between Destructing and ...Spread in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the difference between destruct and ...Spread in the following scenario:

Example using ...Spread

```
function do2(a,b,c){
    alert (a+b+c);    
}

do2(...[5,3,5]);
```

Example using Destructing:

```
function do3({a , b , c}){
    alert (a+b+c);
}
do3([5,3,5]);
```

When do I use each way? Can anyone tell the difference between both ways and which one to use in this scenario? I am still a beginner, so any help would be good.

Answer (score 0):

**Operator Spread**

Spread example:

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
let args = [3, 5];
add(...args); // same as `add(args[0], args[1])`, or `add.apply(null, args)`
```

Functions aren't the only place in JavaScript that makes use of comma separated lists - arrays can now be concatenated with ease:

```
let cde = ['c', 'd', 'e'];
let scale = ['a', 'b', ...cde, 'f', 'g'];  // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

**Destructuring**

Destructuring is a way to quickly extract data out of an {} or [] without having to write much code.

```
let foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

let one   = foo[0];
let two   = foo[1];
let three = foo[2];
into

let foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let [one, two, three] = foo;
console.log(one); // 'one'
```

ES6 also supports object destructuring, which might make uses more obvious:

```
let myModule = {
  drawSquare: function drawSquare(length) { /* implementation */ },
  drawCircle: function drawCircle(radius) { /* implementation */ },
  drawText: function drawText(text) { /* implementation */ },
};

let {drawSquare, drawText} = myModule;

drawSquare(5);
drawText('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example assigns `a`, `b` `c` to to elements of passed array at indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, corresponding to the number of elements in the array

```
function do2(a, b, c){
    alert (a + b + c);    
}

do2(...[5, 3, 5]);
```

The second example expects an object as parameter to the function, `{a , b , c}` destructures the passed object assigning `a`, `b`, `c` as local variables within the function

```
function do3({a , b , c}){
    alert (a + b + c);
}
do3({a:5, b:3, c:5});
```

See also [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread operator at MDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper?s=2|2.5248)

Comment: Yes, I know, so they're the same in this usage? or which one I should be using?

Comment: You can use either approach given current `javascript` at Question. The function is expecting three parameters, three parameters are assigned to variables `a`, `b`, and `c` passing spread element or object having same keys as referenced within function body. Using spread element and array allows not explicitly having to pass object having those properties.